# How to construct all possible paths from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => g
            [1] => hp
        )

    [g] => Array
        (
            [0] => menu
            [1] => submenu
            [2] => icons
        )

    [hp] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat
            [1] => icons
            [2] => banners
        )

    [menu] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [submenu] => Array
        (
            [0] => img
            [1] => icons
        )

    [icons] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => kt
            [1] => hk
            [2] => bm
            [3] => w
            [4] => m
            [5] => at
            [6] => e
        )

    [banners] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [img] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

    [kt] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [hk] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [bm] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [w] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [m] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [at] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

    [e] => Array
        (
            [0] => v1
        )

)
```

Here `images` is the main folder. I want to construct all possible paths of this array starting with `images` as first subArray and if any of the values exists as element in the array itself it is a subFolder too and I want to go through and do the same until I construct all possible paths.

So some possible paths would be:

```
images/g/menu/v1
images/g/submenu/img/e/v1
```

Se how `g` is a value in `images`, but also exists in the array itself. So I go through `g` and there is `menu`, which again exists in the array. Same again go through each values of `menu` which would be `v1` and this doesn't exist in the array. So the constructed path would be: `images/g/menu/v1`.

Comment: So you only want `images/g/menu/v1, images/g/submenu/img/e/v1` from this array? And for what is the `hp` subArray for example?!

Comment: Did you want to make dynamic folder link???

Comment: same like this
hp is another subfolder

Comment: So what are all subFolders? Do they have any order? And what exactly is your full expected output? All possible constructable paths?

Comment: i am expecting the out put like
images/g/menu/v1
images/g/submenu/img/e/v1
images/hp/cat/kt/v1
images/hp/icons/v1
...

Comment: why `images/g/icons/v1`is not in expected list?

Comment: in images folder two subfolders are there (g,hp), in g folder three sub folders are there (menu, submenu,icons) , menu folder one sub folder (v1)

Comment: @PrasadBezawada `images` is the main folder. If an element from images exists  in the array itself it is a subFolder and you want to construct all possible paths?

Comment: @Rizier123, yes, I wanted to get all the possible paths from `images` folder

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Wups, wrong person pinged.

Comment: yes 
i need all possible paths based images is the main folder.
please help me

Comment: @PrasadBezawada Ah okay. So where are you stuck at doing this? Loop through your `images` subArray, check if the value again exists in the array and go through that array if it exists, ... and so on until you construct all possible paths.

Comment: i am stuck in constructing possible paths 
just give small example

Comment: I have tried but i have stuck with construct the full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but this should do the trick:

```
$myArray = [
'images' => ['g','hp'],
'g' => ['menu','submenu','icons'],
'hp' => ['cat', 'icons', 'banners'],
'menu' => ['v1',],
'submenu' => ['img','icons'],
'icons' => ['v1'],
'cat' => ['kt','hk','bm','w','m','at','e'],
'banners' => ['v1'],
'img' => ['e'],
'kt' => ['v1',],
'hk' => ['v1',],
'bm' => ['v1',],
'w' => ['v1',],
'm' => ['v1',],
'at' => ['v1',],
'e' => ['v1',],
];


function getPath($array, $key, $path, &$returnArray) {
    if(isset($array[$key]))
    {
        foreach($array[$key] as $v) {
            $newPath = $path.$v.'/';

            $nextPath = getPath($array, $v, $newPath, $returnArray);
            if(!empty($nextPath))
            {
                $returnArray[] = $nextPath;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $path;
    }
}

$allPaths = array();

getPath($myArray, 'images', '', $allPaths);

echo "<pre>";print_r($allPaths);echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => g/menu/v1/
    [1] => g/submenu/img/e/v1/
    [2] => g/submenu/icons/v1/
    [3] => g/icons/v1/
    [4] => hp/cat/kt/v1/
    [5] => hp/cat/hk/v1/
    [6] => hp/cat/bm/v1/
    [7] => hp/cat/w/v1/
    [8] => hp/cat/m/v1/
    [9] => hp/cat/at/v1/
    [10] => hp/cat/e/v1/
    [11] => hp/icons/v1/
    [12] => hp/banners/v1/
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ji, it is helpful to me